# Apache nifi as cosumer to recieve messages from kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, kafka-consumer-api

I have a scenario where I will have to cosume messages in Nifi Kafka consumer processor from messages sent thru Kafka producer Jar invoked locally ..i am able to consume messages in kafka cosumer console but not in Nifi...how to view messgaes in nifi consumer, if message is in json format

Answer (score 1):

setup your consume kafka processor and link it to a stopped processor.

[image]

right clik on queue > list queue > view details > view .

[image]

Comment: I have done this procedure.. But still unable to retrieve any message sent from kafka producer java jar.. Can you upload properties to be set in consumer kafka record in nifi to receive json Message from producer java jar

Comment: can't because it depend of your kafka configuration. did you see any messages with kafka-console-consumer ?

Comment: Yes consumer is able to receive messages.. But not nifi consumer kafka

Comment: so show us your command line and consumeKafkaRecord processor configuration.